# Method isAdded not working fine, is there other option? Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity(ActivityA) that replace its content by calling a fragment in onResume().

The fragment is a list and when I click on some item another activity(ActivityB) is called.

when I press backButton on ActivityB, it finishes ActivityB. So ActivityA is called and again replace content calling the Fragment.

So far so good, but when the ActivityA is loaded when ActivityB finishes. The fragment starts but its method isAdded() returns false.

What can I do?

Method onResumo on ActivityA:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSecurityControl = SecurityControl.getInstance();

       if (mSecurityControl.hasActiveSession()) {
        if (GeolocationTrackerService.doAsynchronousTask == null) {
            MainActivity.getContextOfApplication().startService(
                    new Intent(MainActivity.getContextOfApplication(), GeolocationTrackerService.class));
        }
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        setTheme(R.style.action_bar_theme);
        EquipmentFragment equipmentFragment = new EquipmentFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, equipmentFragment, "Equipments").commit();
        mUser = mSecurityControl.getUser();
        String email = changeEmailToChannel(mUser.getLogin());
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(email);

    } else {
        LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, loginFragment).commit();

    }
```

backButton onActivityB :

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

where I check isAdded:

```
@Override
public void OnResponseReceived(Object responseObject) {

    if (isAdded()) {
        mEquipmentList = (List<Equipment>) responseObject;
        mAdapter = new EquipmentListAdapter(getActivity(), mEquipmentList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        disableLayoutChildren(true);
        setComponents(true);
```

Comment: Do you need to recreate your fragment in onResume? Probably all you need to do is create the fragment in onCreate on your activity and not replace it on onResume.

Comment: it is because of your code sir

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Francesc it's working fine now